# making a gradebook that reads in from ifstream

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I have to take input from a text file that is in the following format:

```
Attendance: 5
Midterm: 20
Final: 20
Homework: 15
Projects: 40
Henry, Patrick
Attendance: 12 15
Midterm: 80 100
Homework: 50 100
Homework: 60 100
Homework: 80 100
Project: 90 100
Project: 80 100
Project: 75 100
Final: 80 100
```

The first five lines represent the weights for that given category and it's followed by a student's name. Then, a series of grade categories and their scores follow that. The first number represents the score while the second represents the maximum amount of points they could have received. The last grade category is always Final and it may or may not be followed by another student. I have to load this data in and calculate a student's average grade given all these other grades and weights. I have done the following:

```
#include "tmp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream> //for reading and writing to/from files
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string command;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cin >> command;
    ifstream in("grades.txt");
    string Attendance, Midterm, Final, Homework, Projects;
    int A, M, F, H, P;
    in >> Attendance >> A >> Midterm >> M >> Final >> F >> Homework >> H >> Projects >> P;
    
    while(!in.fail())
    {
        if( command == "Load" || command == "load" || command == "l")
        {
            string lname, fname;
            getline(in, lname, ',');
            getline(in.ignore(200,'\n'), fname, '\n');
            string cat;
            int score, possible;
            in >> cat;
            double total;
            while(cat!="final")
            {
                double att, mid, home, proj, fin;
                in >> score >> possible;
                if (cat == "Attendance")
                {
                    att = score/possible*A;
                    total = total+att;
                }
                else if (cat == "Midterm")
                {
                    mid = score/possible*M;
                    total = total+mid;
                }
                else if (cat == "Homework")
                {
                    home = score/possible*H;
                    total = total+home;
                }
                else if (cat == "Project")
                {
                    proj = score/possible*P;
                    total = total+proj;
                }
                else
                {
                    fin = score/possible*F;
                    total = total+fin;
                }
                cout << total << endl;  
                in>>cat;
            }
        }
}
```

The user is asked what they want to do and if they type in load, Load, or l, I'm trying to get it to read in the grades and output the total. (I have a list of other commands for what the assignment asks but that's irrelevant. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file parse" and you will find many questions like yours that have already been answered.